# Is that possible to send HttpWebRequest using TLS1.2 on .NET 4.0 framework

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, httpwebrequest, .net-4.5, tls1.2

My application connects to Experian server and Experian will soon stop supporting TLS 1.0 and TLS 1.1. All connectivity using HTTPS must use TLS Version 1.2.

I want to do some research on that issue and see sending `HttpWebRequest` using TLS 1.2 on .NET 4.0 framework works

If it does not, I will probably need to create a `webservice` on .NET 4.5 and call its methods, if it does, I do not have to anything.

Has anyone already faced with that issue?

Answer (score 124):

Yes, it supports it but you must explicitly set the TLS version on the `ServicePointManager`. Just have this code run anytime (in same app domain) before you make the call to Experian:

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
```

### Update

see [@iignatov 's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41854685/542251) for what you must do for framework v4.0. My code works with 4.5+

Comment: I'm trying to implement that change that you suggested and the only `SecurityProtocolType` options I have `Ssl3` and `Tls`. It does not have `Tls12`

Comment: I'm using that myself to call experian so Tim must be right. It is not HttpRequest that is the problem, it is the framework version.

Comment: As long as you don't have anything at a lower framework level taking a dependency on this code you can just bump up the framework version and add that one line of code.

Comment: Defining explicitly TLS1.2 breaks compatibility with TLS1.1 or older SSL ?

Comment: @AgustinGarzon if you want to support other versions you can "or" them together like: `SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls10`

Comment: This does not work in my 4.0 app, but iignatov's solution does: ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)3072

Comment: @jshockwave yes there is no enum value in 4.0 for TLS1.2 so you have to force it. I was not aware of this at the time but my answer continues to get upvoted I think because people are finding this answer even though they are on 4.5.

Comment: @Crowcoder please update your answer to indicate this only works for 4.5 and above. Otherwise folks who are looking for a 4.0 solution, which is explicitly what the OP asked for, will be going down the wrong path.

Comment: If you want to be future proof you shouldn't set it = explicitly, rather add it w/ |=  - ie. System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol |= System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12

Comment: @Crowcoder there is no such thing as "SecurityProtocolType.Tls10", there is "SecurityProtocolType.Tls" which actually means Tls 1.0

Comment: Thanks for this tip. @Crowcoder 's way is true for .Net 4.5

Answer (score 50):

I had to deal with the same problem, while integrating PayPal into a legacy application, and found the following workaround for .NET 4.0 which seems to do the trick:

```
ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)3072;
ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 9999;
```

Basically the workaround is to directly assign the port for TLS 1.2.

All credit goes to the commenter at [CodeProject](https://www.codeproject.com/Answers/1076045/The-request-was-aborted-Could-not-create-SSL-TLS-s#answer2).

Comment: That magic line did the trick `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)3072` Thanks a lot!

Comment: fyi that hack only works if .net 4.5 is also installed on the server.

Comment: as @CathalMF mentinoed this works only if .NET 4.5 is installed on the server. Unfortunately 4.5 does not support windows 2003.

Comment: Is there a reason to explicitly set ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true ? How it's related with tls 1.2 support? According to documentation it's anyway true by default..

Answer (score 6):

The VB.NET Translation of [iignatov's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41854685/7311767):

```
ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = True
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = CType(3072, SecurityProtocolType)
ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 9999
```

Answer (score 5):

I was solved with this way.

```
    string url = "https://api.foursquare.com/v2/blablabla...";
    var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
    
    var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: Most easiest way

Answer (score 4):

You can also use this:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | (SecurityProtocolType)768 | (SecurityProtocolType)3072;
```

Comment: The Best answer for all solutions is in this link py4u.net/discuss/711097

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately no, you can't do this. Tls12 was not added until .netfx 4.5 (see [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.securityprotocoltype(v=vs.100).aspx)). Note this also requires Windows Server 2008 R2+ or Windows 7+ to run correctly (notice the Applies To section on [Introducing TLS](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd560644(v=ws.10).aspx)).

Comment: @iignatov's answer should work: ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)3072

Answer (score 0):

FrameWork 4.0 does not support TLS 1.1 or 1.2
But you can fix this problem by downloading **Rebex.Http** from Nuget manager.

```
Rebex.Licensing.Key = "..."; //Lisans Number
var creator = new HttpRequestCreator();
creator.Register();

WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("https://www.test.com");
request.Method = "POST";                
request.Headers.Add("utsToken", txtToken.Text);
request.ContentType = "application/json";
request.Method = "POST";

using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
{
    string json = "{\"VRG\":\"test\"}";

    streamWriter.Write(json);
    streamWriter.Flush();
    streamWriter.Close();
}

var httpResponse = (WebResponse)request.GetResponse();
using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
{
    var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
    txtSonuc.Text += result;
}
```

Comment: Rebex.Http is a paid commercial product with a free 30-day trial

Answer (score 0):

```
ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)3072;
```

that's worked for me on .net 3.5

Answer (score 0):

No you can not,

As the source explains,

"The HttpWebRequest class supports only versions 1.0 and 1.1 of HTTP. Setting ProtocolVersion to a different version throws an exception."

Source:
[learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpwebrequest.protocolversion?view=net-7.0)

Answer (score 0):

With an application targeting Framework 4.5 (but with SDK 4.8 installed), none of the above solutions worked for me.

I created a DWORD key `SchUseStrongCrypto` in

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319
```

and

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319
```

with a value of 1.

With this, altering `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol` doesn’t seem necessary.