# WebClient UploadData fails with SSL/TLS Error

Tags: c#, webclient, webclient.uploaddata

I'm using the System.Net.WebClient class (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient(v=vs.110).aspx) to communicate with a REST API of a server. I'm able to do most operations without problems, but I can't get the "UploadData" method to work (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144221(v=vs.110).aspx). When I call that method I get the error "Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel." I have no problem running the corresponding "UploadString" method though. Does anyone have any idea what might be wrong?

To summarize, this method works:

```
public string Post(string endpoint, string body)
{
    return UploadString(new Uri(Uri, endpoint), body);
}
```

But this fails:

```
public byte[] Post(string endpoint, byte[] body)
{
    return UploadData(new Uri(Uri, endpoint), body);
}
```

I've been experimenting a lot with different header settings for the resulting request, but haven't been able to make it work. And I'm rather confused that it complains about that SSL/TLS channel problem and don't see how the two calls differs with respect to that.

Comment: Debug your request somehow (WireShark or Fiddler). There is probably another error hidden behind "Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel". I have seen it popping up when server returns error 400, for example, when providing parameters in bad format.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37869135/is-that-possible-to-send-httpwebrequest-using-tls1-2-on-net-4-0-framework/37869237#37869237

Comment: You were right, Tewr! The parameters was indeed bad, like I described in the answer below. I used Fiddler, like you recommended, to catch it. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had done a mistake in configuring the query parameters. Apparently, one has to remove any preexisting '?' from the query when appending a new query to a UriBuilder.Query property. So I basically had to do a Substring(1) on the query like they describe here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uribuilder.query(v=vs.110).aspx